# Use sound card for audio in and build in headphone Jack for audio out on the raspberry pi 4b

Tags: audio, alsa, audio-playback, usb-audio, speakers

I am currently working on a university project with the raspberry pi. I have build an external microphone which I have to connect to the pi via soundcard. This works fine, it records fine all going well. But when I try to play sound over the build in headphone jack of the pi, it refuses to do it as long as the soundcard is attached. I can take it out, music plays, as soon as I plug it in everything is silent. I have tried to find a solution myself. I have tried 3 pis and 2 SD cards and always the same issue. Ergo I think I am missing something. I have found block posts saying:
This might help but still the same issue:

```
pcm.default {
    type asym
    playback.pcm "plughw:2"   # Playback device: built-in auxiliary port (card 2)
    capture.pcm  "plughw:3"   # Capture device: USB sound card (card 3)
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 2   # Control device: built-in auxiliary port (card 2)
}
```

these are my aplay devices but I mean no surprise there either:

```
test@jo:~ $ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: vc4hdmi0 [vc4-hdmi-0], device 0: MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0 [MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: vc4hdmi1 [vc4-hdmi-1], device 0: MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0 [MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones], device 0: bcm2835 Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 3: Device [USB Advanced Audio Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
test@jo:~ $ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 3: Device [USB Advanced Audio Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Could someone rescue me from this nightmare of config struggles?

Comment: Welcome!  Good question... wish I could help, but I quit trying to configure sound & bluetooth on RPi some time ago. It doesn't seem to be a priority with the RPi organization (otherwise they'd fix this chaos), and I'm not highly motivated as I don't need an RPi in my audio system. Sounds like an interesting project though - best of luck!